# Smart values drop to 0 then comes back up

Tags: hard-drive, hardware-failure, smart

[Acronis Drive Monitor](http://www.acronis.com/en-us/personal/hard-drive-health/) has been sending me the following (email) alerts

```
Disk health has fallen below the warning threshold.
Current health: 59%
Warning threshold: 70%
```

By the time I open ADM, disk health is back at 100%. The ADM event log shows the reason for the alert:

[image]

I am going to install a 2nd monitoring software ([1](http://hddguardian.codeplex.com/) or [2](http://panterasoft.com/hdd-health/)). Due to the sensitive nature of the situation, the question is: **are SMART values dropping to 0 then coming back up right away more likely to be sign of a hardware problem or a monitoring problem?**

*Update: Acronis stopped updating ADM years ago, and I won't be going back from [HDD Guardian](http://hddguardian.codeplex.com/), which has all the functions of ADM except integration with the Acronis Backup Software (it would back up the drive if it detected an imminent failure)*.

Comment: They are not dropping to 0.  They are actually overflowing back to 0.  In other words the actual value is larger then the type of integer being stored can handle.  Based on the number of failures I would say you have serious problems with that particular disk and it should be replaced.

Comment: So you are saying that a lot of different values "overflow" to 0 and back, in a matter of seconds, and this indicates imminent failure? No SMART events have been logged since I started usind HDD Guardian and it doesnt look like a failing drive in it http://i.imgur.com/QNLcLat.png http://i.imgur.com/zKKcrOu.png

Comment: I don't trust HDD Guardian view of the drive, I am looking at your seek error rates and raw error rates, and they are concerning.  What type of HDD is this?

Comment: Seagate ST500LM000

Comment: Seagate offers a Seatools applications.  I would use that.  if that reports the drive as being healthy then you can chop this to a buggy ( discontinued ) Acronis product.

Comment: No warnings so far using HDD Guardian. I will update the question once a week has gone by. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more than 1 week running HDD Guardian and no alerts whatsoever, I have chalked up this situation to a faulty monitor.

Since Acronis does not provide support and no longer maintains ADM, we can not be sure this was the case.

But **it is reasonable to assume that you should test a 2nd or 3rd SMART monitor in this type of situation before writing off your drive as a failing.**